# Конвертация Map в объект через Jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Есть `Map<String, Object>` с полями объекта. Нужно конвертировать эту мапу в объект так как это сделал бы Hibernate, используя колонки `@Column(name="...")`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если задача именно в том, чтобы получить мапу, это можно сделать, например, средствами [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Опишем наши POJO:

```
public class Foo {
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Bar")
    private Bar bar;

    // конструкторы, геттеры, сеттеры, toString()
}

public class Bar {
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("Values")
    private List<String> values;

    // конструкторы, геттеры, сеттеры, toString()
}
```

Теперь можем создать экземпляр и превратить его в `Map`:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(1,
                  "myfoo",
                  new Bar(2000, Lists.newArrayList("foo", "bar", "baz"))
);


ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, ?> map = mapper.convertValue(foo, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

System.out.println(map); // {Id=1, Name=myfoo, Bar={Id=2000, Values=[foo, bar, baz]}}
```

а `Map` можем перегнать обратно в объект типа `Foo`:

```
Foo newFoo = mapper.convertValue(map, Foo.class);
System.out.println(newFoo); // Foo{id=1, name='myfoo', bar=Bar{id=2000, values=[foo, bar, baz]}}
```

Comment: Задача "Map можем перегнать обратно в объект типа Foo", но используя маппинг из аннотаций Column и большую часть остальных интерфейсов. Например, AttributeConverter или Enumerated.

Comment: Т.е. именно обязательно использовать JPA, но с `HashMap` в качестве БД?

Comment: А как быть со всякими `@ManyToMany` ?

Comment: да, верно. Данные поступают прямо из `HashMap`. `ManyToMany` и остальные связи не нужно маппить. В общем случае у меня простые POJO, которые иногда имеют сложные конвертеры атрибутов. Как вариант хотелось бы переиспользовать конвертеры в Jackson, но не вижу адекватного решения с маппингом under_score в camelCase.

Comment: Весьма специфичная задача. Учитывая, что JPA это именно про *реляционные* базы данных, а не KV-/документоориентированные, вряд есть готовое решение.